# reverse encrypting code in php

Tags: php, encryption, reverse

I have the following encryption function, I tried to reverse it but it seems like I miss something

```
$ceva = "123456";
function encrypt($plaintext,$textHos) {
    $textLen=str_pad(dechex(strlen($plaintext)),8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $salt='WSj2g7jTvc8ISmL60Akn';
    $textHosHash=hash('sha256',$salt.$textHos);
    $textHos= md5($textHos,true);
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);  
    $ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $textHos,
                                 $plaintext, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,$iv);

    $ciphertext = $iv . $textHosHash . $textLen . $ciphertext;
    $ciphertext_base64 = base64_encode($ciphertext);
    return  $ciphertext_base64;
}
$data = encrypt($ceva,$textHos);
```

what I tried to do is:

```
$data = 'HpOrKcKS1hwAiFfpbZnijmZmZjg1OWMzOWFlNzRiMzU2Y2JiMTQ5OTY4MTI3MWNiYjQzYjBkMTAyNDUzM2ZhNGJjZmZhNzQ4M2QxN2M0ZGYwMDAwMDAwNu6mYaA+BBBVfbFXChMm/BE=';
$textHos = 'MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128';
$salt='WSj2g7jTvc8ISmL60Akn';
$textHosHash=hash('sha256',$salt.$textHos);
$textHos= md5($textHos,true);
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
$textHosHash=hash('sha256',$salt.$textHos);
$base64de = base64_decode($data);
$mdecrypt = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $textHos, $base64de, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,$iv);
```

then I stopped because my mind has been frozen.
any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to write the code for you but I'll outline the steps. To decrypt you must reverse the steps you did to encrypt, last thing first. So, lets look at the ciphertext and give it a try.

The last thing we did on the encrypt side was base64 *encode* it, so the first thing we do on the decrypt side is base64 *decode* it. That will give us a string of bytes that was created as a concatenation of the iv, the key hash, an 8 character decimal ASCII length of the original plaintext, and the ciphertext. So now you must extract these fields. Fortunately, you know the exact lengths of the first 3 fields.

iv: 16 chars
key hash: 64 chars (hex ASCII, representing 32 bytes)
plaintext length: 8 chars (decimal ASCII)
ciphertext: everything that's left over

In your code you are trying to create a new random IV to decrypt. That's wrong, you must recover the original IV used for encryption and use that IV for decryption. Also, since you transmitted the hash of the key you should hash the decrypt key you're using and ensure it matches the hash sent with ciphertext. You now have everything you need to decrypt the ciphertext. The result will be a padded plaintext. Finally, you use the plaintext length to strip off any padding that may have been added.

Answer (score 0):

You missed this part in the encrypt function:

`$ciphertext = $iv . $textHosHash . $textLen . $ciphertext;`

Before running `mcrypt_decrypt' you need to strip that stuff off the front of the data.